# how to append a row from one dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to identify rows from one dataframe that meet my date criteria in a specific element and then append them to a new dataframe.  I have the identification down, but am having some trouble appending the data to a new dataframe.  "yesterday" is a string containing yesterday's date.

```
    for x in df1.datecompare:
        index += 1
        if x == yesterday:
            dfnew.append(df1.ix[index])
```

Error I am getting

```
TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `append` shouldn't be necessary for what you're trying to do.  You should be able to do it with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
dfnew = df1[df1.datecompare == yesterday].copy()
```

In general, iterating over a DataFrame will be much slower than doing a vectorized operation like what I've done above.

Comment: `In general, iterating over a DataFrame will be much slower than doing a vectorized operation like what I've done above` +1

Comment: Wow thank you!  this seems much simpler and easier!  Unfortunately, I am getting a "series not vectorized" error when I try this.

Comment: Are you actually getting an error, or just a warning?  The only thing I can find related to "series not vectorized" is a performance warning, not an actual error.  I can't reproduce the error/warning.  It probably has something to do with how you're reading in your data.